# Python read CSV to string conversion

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV with following values

```
ID, Value
1, a
2, b
3, c
```

How can I convert this csv to following string using Python

```
[('ID', 'Value'), (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```

I was trying with the following code

```
with open('sample.csv', 'rb') as csvfile: 
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in reader:
        data = ', '.join(row)
        rows.append(data)
print rows
```

Am getting following output only

```
["'ID','Value'", "1,'a'", "2,'b'", "3,'c'"]
```

Comment: `[('ID', 'Value'), (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]` isn't a string. It's a list of tuples. The first tuple contains 2 strings, the other tuples contain an int and a string. So do you want that list, or do you really want a string representation of that list?

Comment: I just want to read the csv that contains two columns like in the question and then need to convert to above mentioned format(even its a string or list or tuples). Am not good in Python. So saying the above representation as string

Comment: Yes, thats working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To produce the list `[('ID', 'Value'), (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]` from that CSV data you need to convert the number strings to integer. Here's one way to do that in Python 2.

```
import csv

data = []
with open('sample.csv', 'rb') as csvfile: 
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, skipinitialspace=True)
    data.append(tuple(next(reader)))
    for num, val in reader:
        data.append((int(num), val))

print data
```

**output**

```
[('ID', 'Value'), (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```

---

The `csv.reader` yields each row of the CSV data as a list. We need to extract the items from that list and convert the 1st one to an `int`. And then we can pack the two items into a tuple and append it to the `data` list. However, the header line contains two strings, so we don't want to perform that conversion on the header line.

This code:

```
data.append(tuple(next(reader)))
```

gets the header line and just converts it to a tuple and appends the result to our `data` list.

---

Note that the Python 2 `csv` module requires you to open the file in `'rb'` mode, but in Python 3 you need to open the file in `'r'` mode. Please see the respective module docs for further details. Apart from that, and using the `print` function instead of the `print` statement, no other changes are needed to run the above code on Python 3.

Comment: If the csv is having more columns then is there any general method to this?

Comment: @PraveenVT Sure, but the best way to do it depends on the types of data in the other columns, eg if there are numbers that need to be converted to `int` or `float`. OTOH, if you just want to read the CSV data and write it back out as a different file format then there's not need to perform that conversion. I suggest you add a short example of your input data with more columns to your new question, and clearly show the desired output format.

Comment: Ok, let me create one sample, but then similar to real data

Comment: added a short example in my new question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47672157/parse-csv-to-create-xpt-file-using-python

Answer (score 1):

Do not read with `rb` but just `r`:

```
with open('sample.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    csvtext = csvfile.readlines()

mylist = []
for line in csvtext:
    mylist.append(tuple(line.strip().split(', ')))
print(mylist)
```

Comment: OP has no issue with it because he probably runs python 2 (in python 3 it crashes immediately). But you're right (that doesn't answer the question though)

Comment: But am getting this out put [('ID,Value',), ('1,a',), ('2,b',), ('3,c',)] Instead i need, [('ID', 'Value'), (1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]

Comment: That means, I need single quotes for character and no quotes for numeric. Or even singles quotes for all value also fine

Comment: No. From my solution you are getting: `[('ID', 'Value'), ('1', 'a'), ('2', 'b'), ('3', 'c')]` which has single quotes for all values as you just requested...

Comment: @mrCarnivore No, am getting like this only
[('ID,Value',), ('1,a',), ('2,b',), ('3,c',)]

Comment: @PraveenVT: That makes no sense. There is a split(', ') this splits the str at the comma and leaves you with two strings. I have tested it. Did you really use exactly and only my code and the file is exactly as you mentioned in your question?